# require file not found using express.static()

Tags: node.js, express

I have main.js as my express server file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('./../app/index.ejs', {});
})
.use(express.static(__dirname + '../app'))
.listen('3000');
```

I did `.use(express.static(__dirname + '../app')) to ask express to make it static`

But I still got error of not found `GET http://localhost:9001/main.jsx 404 (Not Found)`

My index.ejs file look like this

```
<head>
   <script src="./main.jsx"></script>
</head>
<body>Hello</body>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

solved the path isn't correct

It should be

`.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../app'))`